# How to change default path in cmder

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-8.1, cmder

I have Cmder for Windows it has default path c:\Users\ ***username*** and I want to change it to any other path I like or want.  How do I change it ?

Also cmder can replace cmd.exe meaning is it possible to set cmder as default program insted of cmd.exe

[image: cmder image]

Comment: Did you tried to find information in docs? https://conemu.github.io

Comment: @ Maximus it is not conemu it is cmder and i tried searching docs but i didnt got it  http://cmder.net/

Comment: @MandarSant ffs please stop saying this. I have had so many hair pulling experiences with trying to configure conemu with git or the above issue. reading the doc is not enough, because this is not an intended problem ffs

Comment: I think it is bizarre that cmder doesn't use standard Linux/Unix terminology.  User wants to specify $HOME folder.  That should work across all shells available in CMDR.  Instead, we have weird terminology "Startup dir".  But it is not just a startup dir that user wants, user wants place where command like "cd" will always land.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

As of **cmder v1.3.6**:

1. Go to *'settings'*
2. In the settings group *'Startup'*, click on *'Tasks'*
3. Click the console you want to modify (e.g. *cmd::Cmder*, *cmd::Cmder as Admin*, *bash::bash* etc.)
4. Click the button that says *'Startup dir...'*
5. Select the directory you want the console to start up in by default
6. Enjoy

Comment: Works for Cmder version 1.3.10

Comment: Thanks, yes I haven't tested it for lower versions but it should be similar.

Comment: In fact, it is the latest version :)

Comment: Ah yes thanks :) I misread your comment as 1.3.1.

Comment: It should be noted that this solution has side effect that "cmder here" contextual menu does not work anymore. It will always open the startup directory you have set  up. See [here](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1735) for more information. sad :(

Comment: sadly this doesn't work

Comment: @samayo -- could you clarify in what way it doesn't work for you?

Comment: The change doesn't have any effect. Cmder always starts in its default dir. I finally just created a shortcut and assinged the startup dir to it

Comment: Thanks for saving me 10 seconds of my life

Comment: Maybe one important thing to add - to success in step 1 (go into Settings) you need to click "hamburger" icon in bottom-right corner and then choose "Settings...", or you can also click WIN+ALT+P

Comment: still works in cmder v1.3.16

Comment: cmder v1.3.14. If you chose `{cmd::Cmder as Admin}` you may get the error `*cmd is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`  You will need to rearrange the command in the dialog window that is created for you from `-new_console:d:C:\projects *cmd /k ""%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat" "`  to `*cmd /k ""%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat" " -new_console:d:C:\projects `.

Comment: This didn't work for me. What did work was this in Settings/Startup/Tasks {cmd::Cmder} (I have cmder in my %USERPROFILE% dir):

cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat"  -new_console:d:%USERPROFILE% && cd %USERPROFILE%\directory\other_directory

Comment: This breaks the "Cmder here" context menu option, though.

Answer (score 11):

In the `init.bat` file in `~/cmder/vendor`, before

```
:: Set home path
```

add

```
@cd /d "C:/YOUR_PREFERRED_FOLDER/"
```

Comment: i do not want to use cd when ever i open it the path which i have set should remain for ever after closing it also

Comment: It will stay. You are adding this to your init.bat to force it set a new home path.

Comment: where is init.bat file

Comment: init.bat is in the ~/cmder/vendor directory.

Answer (score 9):

1. Create a shortcut to cmdr
2. Edit the shortcut, change the "Start in" path to the desired path
3. Profit

Comment: the easiest solution. :)

Comment: Best solution by far. Easiest & preserves the ability to "Open Cmder here" from context menu.

Comment: Doesn't work with mintty or bash, they can't find the path.

Answer (score 2):

For those who none of the above solutions worked (Cmder keeps reverting back to old path), here's what I did to fix it:

1. Do a text search with Notepad++ in your Cmder directory for `C:/OLD_FOLDER/`
2. Replace each found instance with your new directory: `C:/YOUR_PREFERRED_FOLDER/`.

For me, the issue was in `ConEmu.xml` which was preventing startup folder changes.

Answer (score 1):

In `cmder\vendor\init.bat` there are these lines:

```
:: Set home path
if not defined HOME set "HOME=%USERPROFILE%"
%lib_console% debug_output init.bat "Env Var - HOME=%HOME%"

set "initialConfig=%CMDER_ROOT%\config\user_profile.cmd"
if exist "%CMDER_ROOT%\config\user_profile.cmd" (
    REM Create this file and place your own command in there
    %lib_console% debug_output init.bat "Calling - %CMDER_ROOT%\config\user_profile.cmd"
    call "%CMDER_ROOT%\config\user_profile.cmd"
)
```

So to change your default path for `cmd.exe` all you need to do is to edit your `cmder\config\user_profile.cmd` file and add something like this at its end:

```
if not defined CMDER_HOME set "CMDER_HOME=%HOME%"
cd %CMDER_HOME%
```

I'd recommend using a specific environment variable like `%CMDER_HOME%` because if you use the same `cmder` config on multiple hosts, you can set this environment variable to the appropriate directory on each host and use `cmder` with the exact same configuration. `cmder` provides a default value for `%HOME%`, as you can see above, so that seems to be a safe failback value (you get the same behaviour without that line too, but that's probably because the `cd` failed; which feels nicer to be avoided).

> Also cmder can replace cmd.exe meaning is it possible to set cmder as default program insted of cmd.exe

I'm not sure what you mean by this. `cmder` is just a console emulator that nicely integrates other terminal emulators into its windows. One of these terminal emulators is `cmd.exe`. So `cmder`'s purpose isn't really to replace `cmd.exe`, although most certainly you can just create a new tab in `cmder` whenever you would otherwise spin up a new `cmd` window. It would be probably useful to know *where* and *why* you'd like to use `cmder` by default instead of `cmd`?

Comment: I think he wants to make it his default command prompt... there's a registry setting for that.